# Conjugate gradient, $Ax = b$, when $b$ happens to be an eigenvector

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Suppose in the conjugate gradient method is applied to a symmetric, positive definite linear system $Ax = b$ where $b$ happens to be an eigenvector of $A$. How many iterations will it take to converge to the solution?

I constructed an example and used a computation to solve for $Ax = b$ in this case and it appears that it converges in one (1) iteration. However, I am not sure of the justification for this. Why is this so?

Comment: Just carry out the algorithm with $x_0=0$ and an arbitrary $A$ with $Ab=\lambda b$. In Wikipedia's notation you should find $p_0=b,r_0=b,\alpha_0=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ so that $x_1=0+\frac{1}{\lambda} p_0 = \frac{b}{\lambda}$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks, it's so obvious now, of course.